# Printing progress in command window

Tags: matlab, progress, command-window

I'd like to use `fprintf` to show code execution progress in the command window.

I've got a *N x 1* array of structures, let's call it `myStructure`. Each element has the fields `name` and `data`. I'd like to print the `name` side by side with the number of data points, like such:

```
name1    number1
name2    number2
name3    number3
name4    number4
...
```

I can use `repmat` *N* times along with `fprintf`. The problem with that is that all the numbers have to come in between the names in a cell array `C`.

```
fprintf(repmat('%s\t%d',N,1),C{:})
```

I can use `cellfun` to get the names and number of datapoints.

```
names = {myStucture.name};
numpoints = cellfun(@numel,{myStructure.data});
```

However I'm not sure how to get this into a cell array with alternating elements for `C` to make the `fprintf` work.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way to get `fprintf` to behave as I desire?

Comment: Please provide a representative data set and the desired output, I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. Assuming you're printing these as they're processed, if you're printing progress why do you need `repmat`?

Comment: After posting the question, I can see how it can be confusing. I'll edit my question.

Comment: lets not call it `struct`, as that is the command to create structures

Comment: Of course, my mistake, wrote this in a hurry and it slipped past my MATLAB senses. Should be edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  What I would do is change your `cellfun` call so that the output is a cell array instead of a numeric array.  Use the '`UniformOutput'` flag and set this to 0 or false.

When you're done, make a new cell array where both the name cell array and the size cell array are stacked on top of each other.  You can then call `fprintf` once.

```
% Save the names in a cell array
A = {myStructure.name};

% Save the sizes in another cell array
B = cellfun(@numel, {myStructure.data}, 'UniformOutput', 0);

% Create a master cell array where the first row are the names
% and the second row are the sizes
out = [A; B];

% Print out the elements side-by-side
fprintf('%s\t%d\n', out{:});
```

The trick with the third line of code is that when you unroll the cell array using `{:}`, this creates a comma-separated list unrolled in **column-major** format, and so doing `out{:}` actually gives you:

```
A{1}, B{1}, A{2}, B{2}, ..., A{n}, B{n}
```

... which provides the interleaving you need.  Therefore, providing this order into `fprintf` coincides with the format specifiers that are specified and thus gives you what you need.  That's why it's important to stack the cell arrays so that each column gives the information you need.

---

## Minor Note

Of course one should never forget that one of the easiest ways to tackle your problem is to just use a simple `for` loop. Even though `for` loops are considered bad practice, their performance has come a long way throughout MATLAB's evolution.

Simply put, just do this:

```
for ii = 1 : numel(myStructure)
    fprintf('%s\t%d\n', myStructure(ii).name, numel(myStructure(ii).data));
end
```

The above code is arguably more readable in comparison to what we did above with cell arrays.  You're accessing the structure directly rather than having to create intermediate variables for the purpose of calling `fprintf` once.

---

## Example Run

Here's an example of this running.  Using the data shown below:

```
clear myStructure;
myStructure(1).name = 'hello';
myStructure(1).data = rand(5,1);
myStructure(2).name = 'hi';
myStructure(2).data = zeros(3,3);
myStructure(3).name = 'huh';
myStructure(3).data = ones(6,4);
```

I get the following output after running the printing code:

```
hello   5
hi  9
huh 24
```

We can see that the sizes are correct as the first element in the structure is simply a random 5 element vector, the second element is a 3 x 3 = 9 zeroes matrix while the last element is a 6 x 4 = 24 ones matrix.

Comment: Ah, of course, the output to `A{:}` also takes the remaining rows which does exactly what I want! Also, please excuse my horrible naming choice, it was just a slip of the mind as none of the variable names are from my original code, so I just wrote something quickly. If you could edit that out of your answer, that would be very much appreciated as I'm quite embarrassed. Of course leaving it in reminds me of the shame so maybe that's a good reminder too :)

Comment: @Jens I'm happy to oblige :) Let me edit it now.  There's nothing to be embarrassed about.  Not at all.  I guarantee you that almost every single MATLAB programmer has performed this overshadowing inadvertently... at least once in their lifetime.  I've just learned to make sure I never do it as this has surely bit me in the @$$ before.